# Marketing Cloud Sender Authentification Package

Tags: marketing-cloud, sender-authentication-package

Does anybody know the difference between Domain Authentification and Domain Verification? I know that purchasing SAP or a private domain authentificates the domain but I am not sure what happens if I only verify the domain (at an address level or by registering the domain)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'[Domain Verification](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_domain_verification.htm&type=5)' is not related to Domain Authentication or '[SAP](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_sender_authentication_package.htm&type=5)' and would not provide any of the benefit gained through this process. Domain Verification just provides a way to verify you own the domain,  which is required if you want to use an email address within that domain as the from email.

> Domain Verification and From Address Management are Marketing Cloud Setup features used to verify From addresses used when sending email through Marketing Cloud.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you!

Comment: @GuadalupeInesTapia please mark the answer as accepted if it answered your question